# What site would I ask a question about baseball on TV?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I'm thinking of asking a question about why the box that shows strikes in baseball is still in college baseball games. I know one reason: colleges don't pay to get rid of it, but I don't know the other. I don't know if this would go to the "Sports" website or the "Movies and TV" website.

Comment: I don't have any clue if it'd be on topic on sports but it's *definitely* not on topic on M&TV.

Comment: The TV in "Movies & TV" is about TV *shows*...sports games are not a TV show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various questions on Sports.SE in a similar vein. I'd suggest that is where you should go.

However, you may need to clarify what you mean by "still" in college baseball games.

Definitely not on Movies!

In general, you should look at the help pages on the sites you think may be appropriate (found by clicking on the hamburger icon at the top right, and selecting help)

Comment: It's just that Movies apparently includes TV.

Comment: @TheJavaNub Yes, but if you look at the help center page, it specifically excludes sports. https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic